# GridLayout doesn't fill the screen

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to use Gridlayout. I want my grid's buttons to fill the screen but I have a problem doing that. I notice that the layout itself fill the screen but his children are not filling the layout. This is the output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoKH8.png
I searched a lot on the internet but most of the answers are offering to replace the GridLayout to LinearLayout or RelativeLayout But I have to stay with GridLayout.
Also I dont want to give the buttons specific size but rather stay with the structure in the linked picture.

Here is my code:

```
    <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
android:columnCount="4"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:rowCount="5"
tools:context=".Level1" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:text="0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_1"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_2"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_rowSpan="3"
    android:text="2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_3"
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:text="3" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:text="0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_4"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_rowSpan="3"
    android:text="4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_6"
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_rowSpan="3"
    android:text="6" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:text="0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_5"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:text="5" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:text="0" />

<Button
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="4"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:text="0" />

</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

[GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) : "GridLayout does not provide support for the principle of weight, as defined in weight. In general, it is not therefore possible to configure a GridLayout to distribute excess space in non-trivial proportions between multiple rows or columns ... For complete control over excess space distribution in a row or column; use a LinearLayout subview to hold the components in the associated cell group."

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.80"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="4" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.80"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="5" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.80"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="6" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your efforts, I really appreciate it.But unfortunately like I said I have to use the GridLayout /:

Answer (score 1):

Based on previous answer by @Haresh Chhelana, it worked like so just sharing my solution:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- position 1 -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bt_elsa" />

        <!-- position 3 -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bt_daniel" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- position 2 -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bt_anna" />

        <!-- position 4 -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bt_elmo" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QW0os.png)
source: https://github.com/eduardocerqueira/sing